# How do I make visual indicator when interacting with a tab in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a pad I interact with in my game. How do I make a visual indicator like the one shown in the attached GIF? You see that there is a circle that appears on the tablet showing where the user is about to click.

I have a collider around the tab and on the index finger.

I have tried two methods that did not work for me. One of them is instantiating the game object I intend using as the indicator when the index finger's collider enters the collider around the tablet and then updating its local position to be that of the index finger and some offset. I then destroy it `OnTriggerExit.`

The indicator kind of moves with the index finger but I could not get the exact behaviour I want. I'm also trying to minimise the use of `Update()`

Edit:
Here is the method I tried that is closer to what I want.

```
public GameObject visualIndicator;
private float _moveSpeed = 15f;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("indexFinger"))
    {
        reticle.SetActive(true);
    }
}

private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("indexFinger"))
    {
        Vector3 targetPosition = other.ClosestPoint(transform.position);
        visualIndicator.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(visualIndicator.transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * _moveSpeed);
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("indexFinger"))
    {
        reticle.SetActive(false);
    }   
}
```

For this, I initially have the visual indicator set inactive on the pad. I also have a collider on the pad that protrudes out a bit such that once the finger collider collides with it, the visual indicator is set active and its position is updated to be the position of the point of collision in OnTriggerStay.

This looks very close to what I want but the visual indicator moves a bit up from the pad when looked from the side because its position is updated to be the point of collision of the pad's collider and the finger's. I want the visual indicator to only stay on the pad and follow the finger as shown in the attached GIF.

[image]

Comment: Use a raycast? And what is the issue with using `Update` if the position is supposed to be updated each frame then it needs to happen in Update

Comment: Update happens in every frame of the entire application and might be too costly. The pad is not used every time in the application. It's only needed at some points in time. I have updated my question with what I tried.

Comment: Have you tried the other way around? `Vector3 targetPosition = GetComponent<Collider>().ClosestPoint(other.transform.position);` what you were doing is getting the closest point of your tablet on the finger ... even better though might be to simply raycast from your finger against the tablet and use the hit point directly